# how to search in a collection laravel?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

i have 3 tables , arts(code,designation,prix,qte,gamme_id)
gammes(type)
factures(art_id,prix_total,quantité)
i want to search all gammes between 2 dates in facture table but the problem i dont have relation between factures and gammes , i just have relation between factures and arts

controller

```
public function store(Request $request)

    {
        $prix_totale=0;
        
        $Gammes = Gamme::all();
        $gamme_id=$request->get('gamme_id');
        $date_debut=$request->get('date_debut');
        $date_fin=$request->get('date_fin');
        $articles=Art::where('gamme_id','LIKE',$gamme_id)->paginate(1000);
 
               

          $data =Facture::where('art_id','LIKE',$articles)->whereBetween('created_at',[$date_debut,$date_fin])->orderByDesc('created_at')->paginate(1000);
          foreach ($data as $p) {

            $prix_totale+=$p->prix;

          }

        return view('affairegamme.resultat', compact('data','arts','prix_totale','articles'));
    }
```

index.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('affairegamme.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" width="20" height="20">

    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="col-md-4">Gamme:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                <select name="gamme_id"  id="gamme_id" class="form-control" >
                    <option value="">Select Gamme</option>
                    @foreach($gammes as $gamme)
                    <option value="{{ $gamme->id}}">{{ $gamme->type }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>


         <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4">Date debut :</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="date"   name="date_debut" value="{{ old('date', date('Y-m-d')) }}" class="form-control input-lg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4">Date fin</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="date"   name="date_fin" value="{{ old('date', date('Y-m-d')) }}" class="form-control input-lg" />
        </div>
    </div>   
    
     <br/>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary input-lg" value="Chercher !" />
    </div>

</form>
```

resultat.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    
          <td><h6>ID de facture</h6></td>
            <td><h6>date</h6></td>

          <td><h6>Operation_id</h4></td>
          <td><h6>Article</h4></td>
          <td><h6>Prix Unitaire d Article</h4></td>
           <td><h6>Quantite</h6></td>
           <td><h6>Prix Totale</h6></td>
        

    </tr>
    @foreach($data as $row)
        <tr>
    <td>{{ $row->id}}</td>
    <td>{{ $row->created_at}}</td>

      <td>{{ $row->operation_id }}</td>
      <td> {{$row->art->designation}}</td>
      <td> {{$row->art->prix}}</td>
      <td> {{$row->qte}}</td>
      <td> {{$row->prix}}</td>
            
            
    @endforeach

</table>
<br> </br>
 <h1  style="font-size:200% ;text-align:center">Le chiffre d affaire pour la gamme  est : {{$prix_totale}} dt</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below provided eloquent query will search for the fractures between the provided dates in the fracture table.

```
$grammesBetweenTwoDates = Gramme::whereHas('arts',function($query) use ($date_debut,$date_fin) {
        
        // Any query to apply filter in arts 
        return $query->whereHas('fractures', function($fractureQuery) use ($date_debut,$date_fin){
            
            // Any query to apply filter in fractures 
            return $fractureQuery->whereBetween('created_at', [$date_debut,$date_fin]);
        });
    })->paginate(1000);
```

Since you seem to have problem understanding the answer I will try my best to explain. The above query instructs the database to

1. Find all the grammes that have arts (from grames_id present in arts table ).
2. Find all the arts that have fractures (from arts_id present in fractures table )
3. Find all the fractures that are in between two dates ( from the date provided in eloquent query )

When above all cases match the query return the result.

In the above query you need to have `arts` relation in Grammes model.

```
public function arts()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Arts::class);
}
```

And you need to gave `fractures` relation in Art model

```
public function fractures()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Fracture::class);
}
```

Comment: where i need to write that bro ? in controller ? where exactly ? coz i already have the relations in models

Comment: @Hassen just updated the answer take a look. It will search between two dates and provide you all the grammes in those dates. Place it in controllers

Comment: bro i want to search gammes between 2 dates in table factures 
but the relation is between art and facture (art_id foreign key) i dont have (gamme_id foreign key in factures) so i need to use arts like a pivot